# Is there any way to make a nested ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

By following [this](http://en.wikicode.org/index.php/Custom_ExpandableListView#Custom_ExpandableListView.java) tutorial I was able to make a view roughly laid out thusly:

```
Group1
   child1
   child2
group2
   child1
   child2
```

But I want some more nesting:

```
group1
   child1
       superchild1
```

Any tips on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: me too have to develop nested expandablelistview using hashmap.please give me sample detail description and give me coding wise also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea:

Add your child view which includes both  `child, superchild1` and initially make `superchild1` invisible. Then when `child1` is clicked make it visible. It should be easy for you to code if you make `child1` a checkbox and give it some background you want, and this would also avoid state maintenance.

Comment: i will have to develop nested expandablelistview using hashmap.please give me sample detail description and give me coding wise also.